# How to get the editable grid method call?

Tags: javascript, extjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to test a Extjs based web application. The parameters to be accessed are lying under a editable grid cell. They cannot be edited as reliable as typical web element as it has no static ID.

How can i access the cell(every cell contains div generated by extjs) with unique parameter? else can i call the onclick method of that particular cell(DIV).

In short, where i can find which method is being fired when an editable grid cell is clicked/edited ?

Comment: Are there any `tbody`,`td` and `tr` tags for these grid cells ?

Comment: Yeah,Also, every TD contains a div

Comment: Can you just post html structure for those fields in the grid ?